# Does Spider-Man's webbing have a distinctive odour?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, spider-man

As mentioned by numerous contributors on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Spider-Mans-web-fluid-made-up-of) (not to forget his character in the **MCU**, **the animated series** etc. etc.), Spider-Man made his own webbing using a bunch of chemicals. Although I was not able to find the exact chemical list (*that would obviously be impossible!*), one of the component that I found was a form of ***imbibed est*er** that helped webbing dissolve after an hour.

Speaking about [Esters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ester), they do have a distinctive fruity smell. So could it be possible that Spider-Man's webbing too smelled "***fruity***"?

So does Spider-Man's webbing have actually an odour? I'm open to all forms of answers (comics, Animated series and even the movies)

Comment: A possible source for this might be someone tracking Spider-Man through scent, such as Wolverine or Kraven.

Comment: It's possible that spider man uses a long-chain ester. which wouldn't smell nearly as much. Though since the purpose of the ester is to help the webbing dissolve i find that unlikely

Comment: @Ummdustry well, i'm not sure about the purpose of esters in the webbing either. I just mentioned what i found on the link in Quora.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, instances of people using scent to track Spider-Man haven't ever mentioned using his webbing's scent. As I recall, Kraven (in particular) was more often likely to attract Spidey's attention, rather than actually tracking him (with the possible exception of the "Kraven's Last Hunt" storyline). One expects he would be easier to track as Peter Parker, in which case tracking by web-scent is much less likely.

Comment: I (vaguely) remember an episode in the animated series when Kraven is tracking down Spidey and he smells spidey’s webs to track him back to his house.  But was it the web-scent or just spidey’s stinky suit, idk 

Comment: You’d need the esters in some kind of miscellar form which perhaps reacts with oxygen in the air to start releasing the ester. Given that the suspension is kept airtight and fluid and it only hardens on contact with air, the miscells would need to be pretty robust, otherwise they would burst on the initial spraying. Since that clearly doesn’t happen (if it did, the webbing wouldn’t harden or would be very weak), the implication then is that the miscelles don’t rupture, and therefore you wouldn’t have a smell from the esters.

Comment: Smells like victory!

Answer (score 7):

It definitely has an odour, although I couldn't find anything on how it actually smells beyond "weird". The web fluid also goes rancid if unused for a while, and presumably smells foul as a result.

[image: The web smells "weird".]

<sup>*[Peter Parker: The Spectacular Spider-Man, Vol. 1 #310](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Peter_Parker:_The_Spectacular_Spider-Man_Vol_1_310)*</sup>

[image: Rancid web fluid]

<sub>*[Amazing Spider-Man, Vol. 1 #700](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_700)*</sub>

<sub>Credit to Valorum for finding an image of the relevant page from *Amazing Spider-Man* (see comments).</sub>

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o07x.jpg

Comment: @Valorum Ahh, thank you! I'll edit this into the answer with a credit of course

Comment: If anyone finds or has somewhere to read *Amazing Spider-Man, Vol 1 #700* online don't hesitate to edit a hyperlink into the question the way I have for the other comic.

Comment: Actually I've edited out the illegal filesharing link you put in

Comment: @Valorum Oh, I wasn't aware that was an *illegal* site, my bad, just thought a link to the actual comic was best. I'll avoid such links in the future

Comment: @Ongo "illegal" probably depends on the country (although as a rule of thumb, this did probably violate copyrights), but that site also has pretty much NSFW ads, ahah! In any case that's a good find, +1 :)

Comment: @Jenayah Haha, yeah, I was ignoring them in light of the usefulness as a source... In future I'll follow the example of linking to the wiki page for the comic, even if I get a good image grab from a source with the full comic that's a bit, shall we say, *sketchy*

Comment: Stumbled across [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0MQb.png) if you want to add it :) (_Spider-Man: Mysterio Manifesto_ #1, 2001)

Answer (score 2):

After quite some time, I did find an answer to my own question. In *Marvel Knights : Spider-Man (2004) # 1*, Peter tells Aunt May that he had to wipe his foot marks off the window and had to use a room freshener to get rid of the smell of his web fluids.

[image] 
 <sub>*Marvel Knights Spider-Man # 1 (Page 25); click image to enlarge*</sub>

> You know, I used to check the glass for footprints every morning before I left for school? ***And you wouldn't believe the money I spent on air-freshener to hide the smell of web fluids***

indicating that the webbing had a distinctive smell and probably stank.